# What is difference between DataGrid.Columns.Clear() and DataGrid.DataSource = Nothing?

Tags: vb.net

In VB Net 2003, I'm trying to create a function that can clear my DataGrid of its old data bindings, so that it can get new data.

Since I'm forced to used a more retro program, I decided to try out different clearing methods. I came across these 2 methods.

```
1.
    DataGrid1.Columns.Clear()

2.
    DataGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGrid1.DataBind()
```

When testing number 1, the GridView is completely cleared of everything, data and headers included. While effective, it also means that the GridView is completely wiped out of existence as nothing happens when I try to insert new data.

As for number 2, the data is removed while the header still remains.

Is number 1 and number 2 the same thing? If not what are the differences it does when clearing data bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Number 1: This just removes the columns from the datagrid - the actual data is still bound to the datagrid, but as there are no columns anymore there is nowhere for this data to get displayed.

Number 2: You are just disconnecting the datasource from the datagrid. The columns remain but as there is no data connected, no data can be displayed in those columns.